# Testing express application with mongodb

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs, end-to-end

I have a question regarding the different tests for a node and specifically an express application. 
I am new to node/express coming from a PHP background, so have a few questions.

I know about unit testing, using things like PHPUnit, so I have read about about Jest. My specific questions regarding jest and unit testing in an application like express. Is should I be breaking my code apart more? It currently is quite together my routes are basically where all my business logic is found. Which means it's difficult to unit test?

Then with something else like end to end testing, I am looking at testcafe. For this I am really unsure how to get past my authentication and furthermore how to test on my local machine, before pushing code to production.

Full disclosure, I have a CI setup to my main branch, so I am looking to implement these tests to stop me merging breaking code to my master branch and breaking the production site.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I always prefer mocha.js for testing any node app. It specifies how many test cases are passing, generates a report for those which are not passing. Also it specifies the time required to execute a code segment.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look, any suggestions with regards to interacting with mongodb with mocha.js tests?

Comment: https://medium.com/@danmolitor/writing-tests-for-mongo-mongoose-with-mocha-7e98be740074

Answer (score 1):

I'm also relatively new to node. I use the same stack as you (Express + MongoDB), applying MVC pattern. In Java I used to write a lot of unit tests with Spock, but right now I focus mostly on integration testing.

In my opinion routes should not contain any logic. Try to move it to separate layer - services. This way you can focus on testing logic provided by them, instead of trying to test code hidden in your routes.

For testing I use mocha.js, chai and chai-http.

My approach is to set up test database and form my tests as a sequence of requests. There is no problem with testing authentication that way - just need to correctly set up db with some user data. If you want to cut off the dependencies like database, use sinon for stubbing and mocking.

The obvious downside of this approach is testing time, but you can split tests into unit and integration suites. Run your unit tests locally and integration tests in your CI pipelines.

I'm not sure if it's the best approach, but I'm positive about the effects. Learning new technology means refactoring a lot. I have changed the structure of my project multiple times, moving logic, extracting methods and classes etc. Integration tests assure me that I haven't broken the business logic, despite having changed what's in the black box. This kind of breaking changes would be way harder to maintain with unit tests.